# Show that there is a unique linear transformation $T: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ with following

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This must be a simple question to all of you, but I need serious help understanding how to approach this problem.

I know what it is asking, but I do not know where to start.

Show that there is a unique linear transformation $T: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ with following:

$$T [1\ 0\ 1] = [1\ 2\ 0],\ T [1\ 1\ 0] = [1\ 0\ 0],\ T[1\ 1\ 1] = [1\ 0\ 1]$$

and give standard matrix $A$ for this transformation.

Can someone explain how to approach this (not just a proof or an answer), like what do I do?

Comment: If you can show that $(1, 0, 1)$, $(1, 1, 0)$, and $(1, 1, 1)$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, then a linear transformation is uniquely specified by what it does on that basis.

Comment: Thanks Joppy, but that doesnt help with the whole part where I dont know what to do :)

Can you maybe explain what the first step would be and why?

Comment: Do you know how to show that three vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: Hi Joppy, yes, row reduce and show that there is a pivot in every column of the coefficient matrix. Right? How do I know if I should be using left side of the equal sign vectors or vectors on the right side of the equal sign?

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is doing things in the reverse order, but it works in this case.

Suppose we have such a transformation $T$, with a matrix $A$.

Then we know
$A\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and 
$A\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and 
$A\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

We can combine these into one matrix equation:
$A\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\2&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Using matrix algebra, solve for $A$.  How many solutions do you get?

Comment: How can I solve for A? wouldnt that involve division?

Comment: @Duxa: Yes: with matrices, we don't divide, we multiply by the inverse of the matrix.  If you're doing a course on linear algebra, you should already know how to find the inverse of a matrix, and know that you have to be careful about whether you're multiplying on the left or right of a matrix.  If not, you should revise matrices.

Comment: Hi Frentos, we have not covered invesing matrces yet. So there has to be another way to do this?

Comment: @Duxa: What concepts and techniques have you covered in your course so far?